# How to suppress the verbose from CreateDtm in the textmineR R package

Tags: r

I am very annoyed with this verbose from function CreateDtm() in the textmineR R package, and want to know how to suppress this.

You will always see this verbose regardless of whether you use suppressWarnings(), suppressMessages(), invisible(), or try(silent = T) etc.

the min. reproducible code:

```
dtm <- CreateDtm(c("aa", "ba", "ca", "da", "ea"))
```

the verbose is this progress printing:

```
|======================| 100%
```

Answer (score 2):

I've just added a `verbose` argument to `textmineR::CreateDtm` and `textmineR::CreateTcm` in the development version on [GitHub](https://github.com/TommyJones/textmineR). This version should hit CRAN in the next month or so.

Answer (score 0):

Using the `invisible` function round your function call should suppress the output.

`invisible(CreateDtm(c("aa", "ba", "ca", "da", "ea"))`

If this does not work out, you can use [`sink`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/sink.html) to write the output to a file instead of to the console.

Answer (score 0):

For those who are using a specific version of textmineR (when running under a production environment) where this is not fixed, the following suppresses the printing:

```
# this version redirects output to a variable which can be discarded
res <- capture.output(dtm1 <- textmineR::CreateDtm(c("aa", "ba", "ca", "da", "ea")))

# and the normal call, for comparison
dtm2 <- textmineR::CreateDtm(c("aa", "ba", "ca", "da", "ea"))
identical(dtm1, dtm2)
#[1] TRUE
```

Edit: The code above also works when `CreateDtm` is wrapped by a call to  `suppressWarnings`.